# recyclerview inside coordinator layout scroll issue

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/app_color"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/app_color"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/r1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/app_color"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="39dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                        android:layout_height="39dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/home_name_bg"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                        android:id="@+id/person_letter_cv"

                        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/person_name_letters"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_reg"
                                android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_ios_24" />


                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="Communities"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:id="@+id/heading"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/inter" />

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/home_name_bg"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:id="@+id/search_cv"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/person_letter_cv"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"


                            android:id="@+id/search_view" />


                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/r2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/dark_greyish"
                   android:layout_below="@id/r1">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="195dp"
                        android:id="@+id/logo_cv"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/app_color"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Petromin Community"
                        android:layout_below="@id/logo_cv"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/inter"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:id="@+id/petromin_name" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="158 Members"
                        android:layout_below="@id/petromin_name"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@id/petromin_name"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white_65opacity"
                        android:id="@+id/members" />

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/members"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/inter"
                        android:text="View Details"

                        app:cornerRadius="12dp"
                        android:id="@+id/continue_btn" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/app_color"
                    android:layout_below="@id/r2"
                    
                    android:id="@+id/to_pin"
                    tools:context=".communitySection.CommunityHomeScreen">



                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:background="@color/app_color"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

                        >

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"

                            android:id="@+id/sel_layout"
                            android:layout_gravity="center">

                            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                                android:id="@+id/b1"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
                                android:text="Brand Community"
                                app:cornerRadius="8dp"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                                android:id="@+id/b2"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_greyish"
                                android:text="All Communities"
                                app:cornerRadius="8dp"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/b1"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/b1"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/b1" />

                            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                app:layout_constraintGuide_end="205dp" />
                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/sel_layout"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:text="BRAND COMMUNITIES"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/inter"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:id="@+id/bhead" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="16dp"
                            android:layout_height="16dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/info__4__1"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bhead"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@id/bhead"
                            android:id="@+id/tool" />






                    </RelativeLayout>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tool"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

            android:id="@+id/no_data"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

          >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="274dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:src="@drawable/noda"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/noda"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/noda"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

                android:text="Data Not Found"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/nd_tv"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/nd_tv"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="There is seems to be no data availble to show. try in someother time"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tool"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

            android:id="@+id/comm_rcv" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

first i used recyclerview inside nested scrollview it was very slow , than i used this structure now issue is recyclerview is scrolling to the top even with one item , and if no item the no data image is also scrolling to the top , i want to pin this to_pin layout but this is also going off the screen , what are the alternatives instead of nested scrollview